# How to get the default calculation for certain equation after uncheck checkbox using JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two inputs one of them should have the value of `Quantity` and the other one have the value of `Price` the first input which is quantity of type `number` has `disabled` attribute when check the checkbox the `disabled` removed then; when changing it; it's calculating the total of price and quantity.

For example: `quantity = 2` and `price = 10` so the `total` should equals `total=2*10=20`

But the problem here when uncheck the checkbox I don't want the new calculation. It should get the default calculation that it saved in the database before including the `quantity`.

Based in that here is the sample code explaining my issue:

```js
    $(document).on('click', '.check_box', function(){
        var price = $('.price').val();
        if(this.checked){
            $('.quantity').removeAttr('disabled');
            $(document).on('change', '.quantity', function(){
                var quantity = $(this).val();
                total = quantity*price;
                $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2));
            });
        } else {
            $('.quantity').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            // What should I do in else statement?
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>Item name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_box" /></td>
      <td>Pizza</td>
      <td><input type="number" class="quantity" value="1" disabled/></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" value="20.00" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
Total: <p id="total">40.00</p> <!-- Let's say this total already saved in database before -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to save the original value from database using `data-xxxx` and show it when required.

```
<p id="total" data-original="40.00">40.00</p>

...

$('#total').text($('#total').data('original'));
```

It's better to move the `change` event handler out, otherwise it will attach multiple times when tick/untick the checkbox.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.check_box', function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $('.quantity').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.quantity').trigger('change');
    } else {
        $('.quantity').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#total').text($('#total').data('original'));
    }
});
$(document).on('change', '.quantity', function(){
    if (!this.disabled) {
        var quantity = $(this).val();
        var price = $('.price').val();
        total = quantity*price;
        $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>Item name</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_box" /></td>
      <td>Pizza</td>
      <td><input type="number" class="quantity" value="1" disabled/></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" value="20.00" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
Total: <p id="total" data-original="40.00">40.00</p> <!-- Let's say this total already saved in database before -->
```

Comment: Yes. bro I got it. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry bro. but What if we have more than one input?

Comment: could be similar, but you need to define clearly what is the calculation formula if some inputs are disabled, and some are not.